# Suggestions to prepare a site which is 90% based on a plugin that's still on beta stage?

Tags: bbpress, development-strategy

I want to make a forum site which uses the bbPress plugin for Wordpress (it turns Wordpress into a forum platform). The forums say that the beta plugin shouldn't be used in production.

I want to get some things done, I thought about some elements that may not be affected by changes in the core of the plugin:

- The graphic design part
- The UI part
- The CSS
- Some features

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not using a real forum platform ?

Comment: @soju what do you mean by 'real'? bbPress is not a 'fake' forum platform.

Comment: I mean bbPress is just a wordpress plugin, and wordpress is not a forum platform.

Comment: @bbPress I heard that bbPress is very clean, simple, and I'm already familiar with Wordpress.

Comment: this isn't even a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to use a ready made forum platform like :

- SMF
- phpBB
- Vbulletin
- myBB
- Vanilla

becuase that site is not all forum but also a forum and you want wordpress as your platform then i would suggest you look at [**SimplePress**](http://simple-press.com/) as your forum plugin which is very mature and is constantly updated, packed with features and I can safely recommend it as a forum plugin form wordpress.

Comment: OK I will give it a try.